# A range of objects from a list

Tags: linq

I am having a List of say 100 objects. Now I want to get object from 50th to 60th. How can I do it. I except there will be a simple linq query or lambda expression that I can use.
But I am very new to LINQ and could not find a way searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
var range = objectList.Skip(50).Take(10);
```